# Display object file in Metal

Tags: ios, .obj, metal

I was trying to use metal api to display 3D object and I followed this tutorial (http://metalbyexample.com/textures-and-samplers/) but when I tried to change the Object he use with my object it showed like a block، I'm sorry I can't post an image, it's supposed to be an object for a foot.

I can understand if the object didn't fully display or any thing like this but it didn't have any features just a block.

Any help for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to set appropriate scale of the object you want do display. Also you may need to set appropriate position of your object otherwise it can be clipped by the camera.